# How to add inner border with some padding to an image using imagemagick?

Tags: image, imagemagick

I am using `imagemagick` to add a border to an image.

I can add the border with the following code:

```
convert source.jpg -shave 10x10 -bordercolor red -border 2 final.jpg
```

The code above generates this image:

[image]

However, what i need to generate is something like this:

[image]

If you look at the red border in the second image, you would see the difference between that image and the first image which i currently create using imagemagick.

Could someone please advise on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not say what version you are using or what code laungage either.

```
convert wizard: -stroke red -strokewidth 2 -fill transparent -draw "roundrectangle 10,10 470,627 10,10" output.png
```

If using version 7 you can calculate the dimensions within the command otherwise you need to get the dimensions of the image, do the calculations and input them into the command with a variable.

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to draw a rectangle, but it might be easier to clone, border, and compose an image.

```
convert wizard: -negate \
  \( +clone -shave 10x10 -bordercolor red -border 2 -geometry +8+8  \) \
  -compose atop -composite output.png
```

[image: output]

*Negate added for visibility.*

Comment: Is there any way to give a radius to that red border?

Comment: See bozo's answer by drawing a round-rectangle in place of a simple rectangle. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/#primitives

Answer (score 2):

I get the impression you want to inlay the border a customisable inset from the edges of the image, in which case you should use the version 7 `magick` command and let **ImageMagick** calculate the position itself.

So, let's say you wanted the border 50 pixels in from each edge:

```
inset=50
magick burger.jpg -strokewidth 5 -fill none -stroke red \
   -draw "roundrectangle $inset,$inset %[fx:w-$inset],%[fx:h-$inset] 10,10" result.png
```

[image]

Then, if you change:

```
inset=10
```

[image]